# Stuck Thread Weblogic

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, weblogic

Am using spring mvc with hibernate, application is hosted in weblogic. Getting stuck thread issues on few hibernate calls via DAO IMPL. Could anyone suggest on how to move forward.

```
####<May 21, 2017 9:09:08 AM CDT> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <AUSPWDCPPROD01> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1495375748894> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "624" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 0, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 624704 ms
", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds in "server-failure-trigger". Stack trace:
    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:583)
    org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:442)
    org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:99)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:129)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:247)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:254)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:203)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:56)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.beginTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:387)
    com.dell.dcp.dao.Impl.ClaimDaoImpl.submitClaimAction(ClaimDaoImpl.java:339)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1025.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy271.submitClaimAction(Unknown Source)
    com.dell.dcp.services.Impl.ClaimServiceImpl.submitClaimAction(ClaimServiceImpl.java:68)
    com.dell.dcp.controllers.ClaimController.submitClaimAction(ClaimController.java:234)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1024.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    com.dell.dcp.controllers.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:42)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Comment: Ideally, you should be analyzing the thread dump of the stuck thread. Mostly, it could be a long running sql or i/o related tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due `Session.close();` was not implemented in many places.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it is a real stuck, or is it just a long running service? Weblogic will mark the threads running longer than StuckThreadMaxTime, which is 600 by default. You should check if it is a real problem, or not. If not, then increase StuckThreadMaxTime to a higher value, and you will not get this error. If it is an application problem, then it should be found in the application.

Comment: Its a Hibernate query, to check if user exists or not, which results in stuck thread.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the actual query that `Hibernate` fires? Perhaps your configuration results in an unconstrained query, thus the hanging thread.